# node.js/javascript: trying to set variable equal to the value returned by a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, variables

```
> var score = 6;

> function test(callback) {
    var score0 = 16;
    console.log(score0);
    function callback() { return score0; }; 
    callback();
  }

> score = test()
    16

> score
    undefined
```

The appropriate value for *score* should be undefined. What should I be doing?

Comment: You're missing return statement in your _test()_ function. `return callback();` will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line of *test()* to:

```
return callback();
```

Comment: Thanks, I got killed at a hackathon over this  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to have a callback return a value:

```
function tens(value, callback) {
   return callback(10*value)
}

var n = tens(100, function(result){ return result })

n
  1000
```

Here is another way:

```
function tens(value, callback) {
   return callback(10*value)
}

var n = tens(150,
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err
    else return result
  })

n
 1500
```

The trouble with the way I posed the question is that

```
function test() {
   var score0 = 16;
   return score0;
}
```

would have worked just as well. And if this simplified syntax works just as well, then the function "callback" in my original question is not a callback function but a function that I called by coincidence "callback"